# C# Forms Animation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, animation

I'm wanting to create an animation in C# such as what you would see in a slot machine where the pictures spin round. I know I could manually move the location of a PictureBox or something like that but that seems like not a good idea to me.

How would you guys do it? It doesn't actually matter whether its in standard forms or WPF or anything else similar. Possibly using XNA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use WPF.

With Expression Blend you can easily do the animation you need.
I think I've already seen a slot machine WPF sample somewhere on the web. 
I'll search for it and post it if I find it again

**Edit**

Nope it was a silverlight application, but code is almost the same. Here is the link:
http://www.dolittle.com/Silverlight/SlotMachine/SlotMachine.html

Anyway, if you find that approach to difficult I suggest you read a bit about simple WPF programatically driven animations. They're very easy to do, and with a few lines of code you can accomplish your needs.

Best regards